# Width 100% of space between floated left and right div

Tags: html, css, width, floating

[image: illustration]

I have a div on the left side and on the right side, both fixed width. I have a middle div witch is also fixed width. I want the middle div to stay in the middle of left and right div no matter screen reslolution, so the space from left to mid div and space from mid to right div shold be the same allways. How can i do that?

This is what i got so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}
#container{
    width: 100%;
}
#left{
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}
#content{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#right{
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZCT/

Comment: [What about this?](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZCT/2/)

Comment: No, the content has a fixed width. I want the sapacing between left div <- mid div AND mid div -> right div to expand/colapse all depending on resoloution (Ex. screen res 1280px, total divs width 300px, so margin left and right on mid div = 460px)

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZCT/3/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the `left` and `right` divs absolutely and have the `center` div in the middle.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#left {
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
#right {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZCT/1/)

Comment: This make content center of screen, not the right and left div.
Also i want to avoid position cause later on i will implant a footer there should be relative to these divs